Spectral clustering through kernlab R package not working for signature kernelMatrix
Note the documentation of kernlab::specc() method on page-92 of the reference manual. It's possible to pass an instance of kernelMatrix class to the function. However, when I do that with 'nystrom.red' argument set to 'TRUE', I get an error; screenshot next . On noticing that the documentation for nystrom.red argument talks about 'nxm' matrix, I tried setting values to 'n' and 'm', but get another error; screenshot next .
I'm inclined to believe that the documentation is incomplete, and/or there is a bug. Any opinions? Using R 4.3.2. Dataset really large, difficult to insert here. Process to generate kernelMatrix instance: .
Edit 2024-04-04:
Here is a sample code, and the corresponding output with error.
library(parallelDist)
library(kernlab)
#library(KERE)
d <- parallelDist::parDist(as.matrix(data.frame(clm1=c(11,3,5,7,9,13),clm2=c(2,4,6,8,10,12))), method='euclidean')
d^2
d_sqrd <- as.matrix(d^2)
d_sqrd
gausKern <- exp((-0.5)*(d_sqrd))
gausKern
#gausKernMat <- KERE::as.kernelMatrix(gausKern)
gausKernMat <- kernlab::as.kernelMatrix(gausKern)
gausKernMat
set.seed(17)
nk=2
#n=floor(dim(gausKernMat)[1]/2)
#m=floor(dim(gausKernMat)[2]/2)
sc_rbf_handRep_nk <- specc(
x=gausKernMat,
centers=nk,
#kernel="rbfdot",
#kpar=list(sigma=0.5),
kpar='automatic',
nystrom.red=TRUE,
#nystrom.sample=n*m,
#iterations=500,
)
sc_rbf_handRep_nk@size


The 'non-conformable arguments' error (in the second image from top) arises when there's an attempt to multiply incompatible matrices. If 'n' and 'm' are indeed required to be specified (which is still not certain since the documentation doesn't state that), I suspect this error is thrown while specc() is computing graph Laplacian (assuming NJW algorithm is implemented, though it's nowhere specified in the documentation). My hunch is that the sub-matrix to be computed using n & m isn't working right, leading to problems w/ graph Laplacian.
